# Getting a list of all events that can potentially pass through an angular scope. $$listenerCount?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, dom-events

Inside a directive I am trying to get a list of all event names that can potentially be captured by the given scope.

When observing the scope object, I can see that there is a `$$listeners` property, which contains a single function, and a `$$listenersCount` property, which does in fact seem to contain a list of events which I have defined that are relevant to the given scope.

[image: $$listenerCount properties]

I am listening to most of these events on child scopes of the one that is displayed, so I'm assuming this is a list off all events "passing through" the given scope, not events which the specific scope is listening to. I'm unsure what the numbers mean, though.

I can't find any documentation on these properties so I am assuming they are an internal thing that shouldn't be used for this specific purpose.

Are there any other ways of retrieving a list such as this or do you think it's safe to use despite the lack of documentation?

Comment: [The code is a pretty good documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#L1014), but I guess we can have a very good answer here ;) . For information, properties beginning with `$$` are strictly private and should not be used (the BC is not guaranteed, for instance).

Comment: @Blackhole hah yeah, I kept thinking what it was about the look of those properties that seemed weird, sure enough it was the double dollar!

Comment: [Here is the reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api) : "To prevent accidental name collisions with your code, Angular prefixes names of public objects with `$` and names of private objects with `$$`. Please do not use the `$` or `$$` prefix in your code."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first consider using $$listeners. Like [@Blackhole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057033/blackhole) quoted in his comment:

> To prevent accidental name collisions with your code, Angular prefixes names of public objects with $ and names of private objects with $$. Please do not use the $ or $$ prefix in your code.
>
> [-Angular Api](https://docs.angularjs.org/api)

So $$listeners is private to angular. It has no documentation and can introduce a breaking change at any moment without notice. Also it's not exactly what you want. By looking at the code of [$scope.$on](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.0/src/ng/rootScope.js#L1130-L1153) we can see that, like you guessed, $$listenerCount bubbles up the scope to its $parent, all the way to root. The numbers are a count of how many listeners are listening to that one event. You might be able to get away with using $$listeners if you were developing some internal tool to debug events, but using in a production site would not be the wisest thing.

---

So what would be a documented way to achieve this? Angular provides a [decorator method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#decorator) on its provider. While the documentation on this is little, it is quite a powerful tool. It essentially allows interception of any part of angular, and act as a man in the middle (see more info on the [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and [Monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) on Wikipedia). Using these tools we can create a configuration that will capture each instance of $on being called:

```
.config(function ($provide) {
    function wrap(oldFn, wrapFn) {
        return function () {
            return wrapFn.bind(this, oldFn)
                         .apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }

    $provide.decorator('$rootScope', function ($delegate) {
        var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf($delegate);

        proto.$on = wrap(proto.$on, function ($on, name, listener) {
            var deregister = $on.call(this, name, listener);
            console.log(this, name, listener, deregister);
            return deregister;
        });

        return $delegate;
    });
});
```

Here I have logged each time $on is called. The $scope is the `this` variable, `name` and `listener` are the arguments passed to $on, and `deregister` is the return value. Note that his requires ES5's [Object.getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf), and will add overhead each time $on is called.

From here, getting the potential event listeners is easy. Instead of console.log, you could place them into a map, or hook into specific ones. You could also wrap the listener or delistener and do additional work every time they get called. Here is an [example plunker of that](http://plnkr.co/edit/U5P3cSNtUtD6fKaHX0rV?p=preview).

This is better than using $$listeners, because $$listeners can change in any way, at any time. $on on the other hand, is a published API. It will be far more stable, and it will not change without a "Breaking Change" notification in angular's changelog and is the safer choice, even though it uses more anomalous tools.